# VUnit: ERROR - Cannot add library named work using `udp_ip_stack-master`

Tags: vhdl, verification, xunit, modelsim, vunit

Wanted to try out [VUnit](https://vunit.github.io/#), thus followed the [Getting Started 1-2-3](https://vunit.github.io/posts/2017_01_12_vunit_getting_started_1_2_3/post.html).

For blog 1, I installed Python ver. 3.6 and using ModelSim ver. 10.5a.

For blog 2, I downloaded example project [udp_ip_stack-master.zip example project](https://github.com/LarsAsplund/udp_ip_stack), but when I run:

```
python run.py --compile
```

the result is the error shown below:

```
C:\work\udp_ip_stack-master>python run.py --compile
  ERROR - Cannot add library named work. work is a reference to the current library. http://www.sigasi.com/content/work-not-vhdl-library
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\vunit\ui.py", line 728, in main
    all_ok = self._main()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\vunit\ui.py", line 765, in _main
    return self._main_compile_only()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\vunit\ui.py", line 820, in _main_compile_only
    self._compile(simulator_if)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\vunit\ui.py", line 855, in _compile
    continue_on_error=self._keep_compiling)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\vunit\simulator_interface.py", line 133, in compile_project
    self.setup_library_mapping(project)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\vunit\modelsim_interface.py", line 143, in setup_library_mapping
    project.add_library(library_name, library_dir, is_external=True)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\vunit\project.py", line 68, in add_library
    self._validate_library_name(logical_name)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\vunit\project.py", line 60, in _validate_library_name
    raise RuntimeError("Illegal library name 'work'")
RuntimeError: Illegal library name 'work'
```

This project should not define any library named `work`, and as example project I would expect that it worked out of the box.  What can be the problem?

Comment: Try somewhere other than `c:\work` perhaps?

Comment: Just tried at "C:\tryout>", but same result.  I have also tried with ModelSim ver. 10.4 EDU, and Python ver. 2.7.x, but these give the error.

Comment: OK. There's a gitter channel linked to the vunit github website, I've found it helpful.

Comment: Thanks Brian; your indication that it should work made me dig deeper, this found the reason and posted it in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "modelsim.ini" file contained:

```
work = work
```

and this made VUnit break with the mentioned error.

I suspect that quite a number of simulations uses work as an actually library name, doing for example `vlib work` in ModelSim, and this actually works fine, so maybe worth allowing this in VUnit, unless there is a substantial reason for not allowing this.

Comment: In VHDL, `work` is a reference to the current library, much like `self` in Python and `this` in Java and C. You can use the `work` library inside your VHDL to refer to the current library, but it is considered a bad practice to use `work` to name libraries.

I have cloned the repo (https://github.com/LarsAsplund/udp_ip_stack) and couldn't reproduce the problem.

Which VUnit version are you using?

Comment: Using latest VUnit, but as I wrote in this answer, the problem was solved by removing the `work = work` line in the "modesim.ini" file used for Modelsim setup.  So if you really want to reproduce the problem, you should try to insert a `work = work` line in your "modelsim.ini" file.

Comment: It has been a long-lasting frustration to 'advanced' VHDL users that ModelSim uses `work` as a standard name for a library, or that you can use it as a nema _at all_. As souto says, `work` is actually a VHDL **keyword** that refers to the _current_ library.